# criar um novo child com mesmo nome invés de sobreescrever-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

preciso de ajuda em firebase
eu tenho um código que cria um "child"(acho que é assim que se chama) chamado "records" dentro do nó(pasta/table) chamado "usuários" que recebe um valor passado por parametro, porém sempre que esta função é chamada e este código é executado eu gostaria que invés de sempre sobreescrever o child "records" gostaria que fosse criado outro com o mesmo nome(records) com o valor passado, ou seja, sempre que chamar a função criar um child, meu código está assim:

```
      async setRecord(recordPoints){
      const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      return await firebase.database().ref('usuarios').child(uid).child('records').set({
        record: recordPoints
      })
  }
```

obrigado desde já :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste seu exemplo é necessário usar o `push` no lugar do `set`, conforme consta na documentação:

> Add to a list of data in the database. Every time you push a new node onto a list, your database generates a unique key, like messages/users//

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

No seu caso, seria algo como

```
async setRecord(recordPoints){
      const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      return await firebase.database().ref('usuarios').child(uid).child('records').push({
        record: recordPoints
      })
  }
```

Comment: mt Obrigado mano, funcionou aqui, se é foda!