# Firebase substitui a informação ao invés de adicionar

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, app, kotlin

Estou fazendo uma app de tarefas com kotlin e firebase, mas cada vez que tento adicionar informação á minha base de dados, ele não adiciona ela mas substitui a anterior.

Esse é o meu código:

```
class AddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)
}
fun function4(view: View){
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/$uid-posts")
    val user2 = AddActivity.User2(editText3.text.toString(), editText4.text.toString())
    ref.setValue(user2)
    val intent2 = Intent(this, TasksActivity::class.java)
    intent2.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent2)
}
class User2(val title: String, val content: String)}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [criar um novo child com mesmo nome invés de sobreescrever-firebase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430549/criar-um-novo-child-com-mesmo-nome-inv%c3%a9s-de-sobreescrever-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerendo apenas o título e o código apresentado, mais especificamente `users/$uid-posts`, creio que o seu objetivo seja ter uma lista de "posts" e esteja usando incorretamente o método `setValue` para isso. Neste caso, o método correto é o `push`, conforme a documentação, esse deve ser o método usado para "criar novos elementos dado um local especificado":

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()

> Create a reference to an auto-generated child location.